# How to fix the error in GML: non-planar polygon distance

Tags: geometry, error, gml, citygml, building

I have validated the GML data in the CityDoctor. It found the error "GE_P_NON_PLANAR_POLYGON_DISTANCE_PLANE" in nearly all of the buildings. Is there a short way to fix such an error?

Comment: Does CityDoctor have any documentation about the errors that it can find?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not. There are these links regarding the definition of the error: https://gitlab.com/volkercoors/CiD4Sim/-/wikis/healing/GE_P_NON_PLANAR_POLYGON_DISTANCE_PLANE                   https://gitlab.com/volkercoors/CiD4Sim/-/wikis/validation/Requirements/ge_gml_po_0002

Comment: The error means that some polygons are not flat. If you place a non-flat polygon on a glass table, at least one vertex does not touch the glass. There must be tools for fixing this kind of errors but unfortunately I do not know them.